# Make jQuery Tabs work without the <a> tag

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have the following code for Tab functionality, it works great and the way I want it, but I want it to work without the `<a>` on the tab navigation.

```
$(function () {
  $('.tab-content:not(:first)').hide();
  $('#tab-nav a').bind('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    $target = $(this.hash);
    $('#tab-nav a.current').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content:visible').fadeOut("fast", function () {
        $this.addClass('current');
        $target.fadeIn("fast");
    });
  }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

Please check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Delinx/yrhcy5qq/) link to better understand what I mean. I tried to get rid of the `<a>` tag and use `<li>` instead. I want it in such a way that I can choose to use `<li>` tag or `<div>` tag. Just not an `<a>` tag.

I tried to get rid of the `<a>` tag and use `<li>` instead as shown below, but [it doesn't appear to be working](http://jsfiddle.net/Delinx/xeja55wa/):

```
$(function () {
  $('.tab-content:not(:first)').hide();
  $('#tab-nav li').bind('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    $target = $(this.hash);
    $('#tab-nav li.current').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content:visible').fadeOut("fast", function () {
        $this.addClass('current');
        $target.fadeIn("fast");
    });
  }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

I could really use some help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't duplicate `ID`'s, use another attribute and get the target from there

Comment: @charlietfl What do you mean you can't duplicate `id`'s..? I couldn't find where OP is duplicating `id`'s...

Comment: @TJ, in the second fiddle without the `<a>`. The tab's `<li>` have same ID as content elements

Comment: @charlietfl oops, i didn't notice the non-working fiddle.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For identifying the target, You can use a `data-*` attribute rather than the `href` of anchor tag so that you can use any elements you wish for creating the navigation by adding the respective data attribute.

Also, for identifying the navigation items, you should add a common class to them. I'm using the class `nav-item` in the following example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.tab-content:not(:first)').hide();
  $('#tab-nav .nav-item').bind('click', function(e) {
    $this = $(this);
    $target = $($this.data("target")); // get the target from data attribute
    $('#tab-nav .nav-item.current').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content:visible').fadeOut("fast", function() {
      $this.addClass('current');
      $target.fadeIn("fast");
    });
  }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

```css
#tabs-wrap {
  background: #ececec;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.container {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.tab-inner {
  padding: 20px;
}
/* Tab Navigation */

#tab-nav-wrap {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 0;
  background: #252525;
}
#tab-nav-wrap #tab-nav {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}
#tab-nav .nav-item {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}
#tab-nav .nav-item.current, #tab-nav .nav-item:hover {
  border-bottom: 0px solid #ececec;
  background: #6a6a6a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="tab-one" class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
    <!-- ends tab-one -->
    <div id="tab-two" class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-inner">Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te
        feugait nulla facilisi.</div>
    </div>
    <!-- ends tab-two -->
    <div id="tab-three" class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-inner">Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius.</div>
    </div>
    <!-- ends tab-three -->
    <!-- Tabs Navigation -->
    <div id="tab-nav-wrap">
      <ul id="tab-nav">
        <li class="nav-item" data-target="#tab-one">Tab One</li>
        <li class="nav-item" data-target="#tab-two">Tab Two</li>
        <li class="nav-item" data-target="#tab-three">Tab Three</li>
      </ul>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- ends tab-nav -->
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- ends container -->
</div>
<!-- ends tabs-wrap -->
```